# SharePoint RTE: How to attach to mousedown events (like bold, italic does)

Tags: 2010, javascript, ribbon, rich-text, rte

When clicking on **bold** text in the RTE (rich text editor), magically the ribbon button for bold gets activated, as you can see here.

[image: toolbar with bold icon toggled on]

The same happens for the other format option buttons you can see on the screenshot. I want to attach to this same functionality, but I don't know how to do this. Somehow the SP Javascript must check the text the mouse just clicked, check its current style (bold) and send this information to the ribbon which in turn activates the bold button so you can deactivate (toggle) it.

There is a [very good example of adding a custom markup button](http://blog.andersdissing.com/2011/11/playing-with-sharepoint-rich-text.html) (in this case adding a `<span class="highlight"></span>` around the currently selected text) to the ribbon. Unfortunately this only adds the markup. Of course I could edit the code to check [pseudocode] `if exists <span class="highlight"> --> remove` so I would have a toggle button for the highlight function - what I don't have is that the button is highlighted once someone selects text with `class="highlight"`.

What I figured out so far: When you click on a **bold** text or e.g. [a link](http://example.org) within a rich text editor in SharePoint, a `mousedown` Javascript event is fired from `MicrosoftAjax.js`. This gets passed on to `SP.UI.RTE.js` via Callbacks. I also found `RTE.Cursor` (or `RTE.Canvas.onMouseDown` in particular) in some tutorials being used, so maybe I can get notified somehow that the cursor currently resides on `class="highlight"`?

One thing I could do is to write a custom `OnMouseDown` event handler and do the same thing SP does - but maybe there is some way I could attach to the same event Microsoft is currently attached to?

Some resources:

- [Add your own shortcut key functionality in Enhanced rich text box of SharePoint 2010](http://lokeshkhinchi.wordpress.com/2010/11/15/add-your-own-shortcut-key-functionality-in-enhanced-rich-text-box-of-sharepoint-2010/)
- [Creating Notes://-links in SharePoint 2010's Rich Text Editor (RTE)](http://sharepointblog.buus-oestergaard.dk/post/Creating-Notes-links-in-SharePoint-2010s-Rich-Text-Editor-%28RTE%29.aspx)
- [Creating a ribbon item similar to the reusable content menu](http://www.intheknow.it/ribbonflyoutpreview.ashx?HL=ribbon)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have two options here. **One** is to create simple toggle button with this markup:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Elements xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/">
  <CustomAction Id="8DCC5B17-4B9E-41A7-BA51-65CBC6F8205D"
                Location="CommandUI.Ribbon"
                Sequence="10">
    <CommandUIExtension>
      <CommandUIDefinitions>
        <CommandUIDefinition Location="Ribbon.EditingTools.CPEditTab.Font.Controls._children">
          <ToggleButton
            Id="Ribbon.EditingTools.CPEditTab.Font.CustomRTEToggleButton"
            Alt="My Custom Action"
            Command="CustomRTEToggleButton.Action"
            QueryCommand="CustomRTEToggleButton.Query"
            Sequence="55"
            TemplateAlias="o1"
            Image16by16="/_layouts/1033/images/formatmap16x16.png" Image16by16Top="-112" Image16by16Left="-16"
            ToolTipTitle="My Custom Action" 
            ToolTipDescription="My Custom Action."/>
        </CommandUIDefinition>
      </CommandUIDefinitions>
      <CommandUIHandlers>
        <CommandUIHandler
          EnabledScript="return true;"
          Command="CustomRTEToggleButton.Action"
          CommandAction="javascript:alert('hello there');" />
        <CommandUIHandler
          EnabledScript="return true;"
          Command="CustomRTEToggleButton.Query"
          CommandAction="javascript:alert('query');" />
      </CommandUIHandlers>
    </CommandUIExtension>
  </CustomAction>
</Elements>
```

alert with "query" will be shown every time when you click (or select text) in rte text editor (this event will be also fire when tab with button will be loaded). So, you can create js function (instead of alert) that will be analyze cursor position somehow (or selected text) and perform required actions. The only trouble is to find correct way to toggle display mode for button. Example of javascript for manipulating with selected text:

`var selectedText = RTE.Cursor.get_range().get_text();` - returns selected text
`var parentEl = RTE.Cursor.get_range().parentElement()` - returns DOM element, which contains current cursor.

**Another option** is to create custom page component ([here](http://www.andrewconnell.com/blog/archive/2010/10/11/implementing-page-components-in-the-sharepoint-ribbon.aspx) and [here](http://blog.mastykarz.nl/sample-code-asynchronously-checking-ribbon-command/) good explanation with examples). Using second approach your definition should look like this one:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Elements xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/">
  <CustomAction Id="8DCC5B17-4B9E-41A7-BA51-65CBC6F8205D"
                Location="CommandUI.Ribbon"
                Sequence="10">
    <CommandUIExtension>
      <CommandUIDefinitions>
        <CommandUIDefinition Location="Ribbon.EditingTools.CPEditTab.Font.Controls._children">
          <ToggleButton
            Id="Ribbon.EditingTools.CPEditTab.Font.CustomRTEToggleButton"
            Alt="My Custom Action"
            Command="CustomRTEToggleButton.Action"
            QueryCommand="CustomRTEToggleButton.Query"
            Sequence="55"
            TemplateAlias="o1"
            Image16by16="/_layouts/1033/images/formatmap16x16.png" Image16by16Top="-112" Image16by16Left="-16"
            ToolTipTitle="My Custom Action" 
            ToolTipDescription="My Custom Action."/>
        </CommandUIDefinition>
      </CommandUIDefinitions>
    </CommandUIExtension>
  </CustomAction>
</Elements>
```

and code in you `handleCommand` in page component something like this:

```
handleCommand: function (commandId, properties, sequence) {
        if (commandId === 'CustomRTEToggleButton.Query') {
            var selectedText = RTE.Cursor.get_range().get_text();
            if (/SP/gi.test(selectedText)) {
                properties.On = true;
            }
            else {
                properties.On = false;
            }
        }
    },
```

`properties.On` controls if toggle button active or not.
Second approach is a little bit complected, but this is more sharepoint-like style plus you can automatically switch your toggle button using `properties.On`.

**NOTE**: QueryCommand attribute available only for several ribbon controls.

**UPDATE**:
I've created sample solution using second approach, it adds toggle button to the ribbon, the button become active, when we select word `sharepoint` in the rich text area. Currently it can be downloaded from [here](http://spblog.net/file.axd?file=2012%2f4%2fCustomRTEToggleButton.zip). The only problem - I can't figured out how to make button smaller, I've tried different `TemplateAlias` but with no luck, if you find correct option to make it smaller (as other buttons like bold, italic, etc) please comment. Currently it looks like on the screenshot: 
[image]

Comment: +1 cause that is an impressive answer! Can you clarify when you'd use option one vs option two? Is it just less complicated?

Comment: As Andrew Connell mentioned, you should use page component `because the page component is an actual client object, you have all the power of an object such as private methods and fields if you need to store state`, so if you have complicated logic in your handler, you should use page component. In this question, if we are using first option, I really don't know how to switch on (or off) toggle button (may be somehow using js ribbon api, get button instance by id), but if you are using second option, you can toggle button using `properties` object.

Comment: Good answer! However I couldn't reproduce your first example. I got the button to load correctly but when clicking it no alert appears. I don't see how the two examples **know at all times** what the cursor currently resides on. I don't want to *click a button* and then it changes its toggle state according to the currently selected text - I want this to be live on cursor click within the RTE.

Comment: I've created test solution, see my update. Regarding the first option it works for me. You don't have to click toggle button to change it state, the state changes automatically depending on user actions in the rich text area. Sorry for late reply.

Comment: amazing answer.

Comment: Just awesome Kai.

Comment: @Kai you will not be able to create smaller buttons inside the `FontGroup`. It only has one overflow section where the `displaymode` is set to Large - hence the large button. You can look at the `CMDUI.XML` and checkout the `GroupTemplate` `Ribbon.Templates.FontGroup` to see what I mean. You would have to create your own group for your own sizes.