# Is there a way to wrap text editor content with html tags?

Tags: list, rich-text

I'm trying to implement syntax highlighter in SharePoint and have it working, but want to be able to use it in a list using a multi-text field. I would like to wrap the text that I paste into the editor with the `<pre class>` and `</pre>` tags with SyntaxHighlihter uses. Any ideas as to how to inject those tags into the RTE would be helpful!

Comment: If this is 2010.. have you seen this question? http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/34089/sharepoint-rte-how-to-attach-to-mousedown-events-like-bold-italic-does

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Shnt Highlightrer for SharePoint](https://sharenotes.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Syntax%20Highlighter%20For%20SharePoint) or take a look at source files as a start point for own implementation.